# -ISSUE- AngularMeteor,Meteor or Angular

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

thanks for read

Comportamientos:

when the result `verCandidatos.postulados`  only have one value (like rectangle in img) never print the first time, I need refresh or click again and print values why?

**html client**

my-app/imports/ui/components/vacantes/verCandidatos/verCandidatos.html

```
<div ng-repeat="postulado in verCandidatos.postulados">
      {{postulado.candidato().nombre}} 
      {{postulado.candidato().apellidos}}
      {{postulado.candidato().sexo}}            
</div>
```

Next the images:

//////////// ISUE  img1

[image]

//////////// ISUE  img2

[image]

**js in client**

my-app/imports/ui\components/vacantes/verCandidatos/verCandidatos.js

```
imports ...

class VerCandidatos {
    constructor($scope, $reactive, $stateParams) {
        'ngInject';
        $reactive(this).attach($scope);
        this.vacanteId = $stateParams.vacanteId;
        this.subscribe('vacantes.candidatosOseleccionados', ()=> 
            [
                  {vacanteId: this.vacanteId}, 
                  {estado: 1}
            ]
        );
        this.helpers({
            postulados (){
                return Postulaciones.find();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**collection.js**

my-app/imports/api/postulaciones/collection.js

```
imports...

export const Postulaciones = new Mongo.Collection('postulaciones');

Postulaciones.deny({...});

Postulaciones.helpers({
    candidato(){
        return Candidatos.findOne({_id: this.candidatoId});
  }  
});
```

**publish.js:**

my-app/imports/api/vacantes/server/publish.js

```
imports...

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publishComposite('vacantes.candidatosOseleccionados', function (vacanteId, estado) {
        const selector = {$and: [estado, vacanteId]};
            return {
                find: function () {
                    return Postulaciones.find(selector);
                },
                children: [
                    {
                        find: function (postulacion) {
                            return Candidatos.find({_id: postulacion.candidatoId}, {
                                fields: {
                                    nombre: 1,
                                    apellidos: 1,
                                    sexo: 1,
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                ]
            };
    });
}
```

**Any ideas?**
- Thanks,